# How to use db:schema:load without erasing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm missing plenty of migrations **files** in my Rails... and I have data I don't want to lose data in production.

I want to deploy new features, but if I use `db:schema:load` Ill erase my production data.

Is there any way to use it without wiping up the ddbb?

Thanks

Comment: If you're missing the actual *files*, you're pretty screwed from a Rails standpoint. You need to manually introduce the equivalent changes. You cannot `db:schema:load` without dropping your current database. How on earth did you wind up missing the migration *files*? You *need* to commit those to the repository, that's the entire point of using migrations to introduce change.

Comment: I really don't know. I'll have to make the migrations again :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database that's missing migrations, you should just *run those migrations*.

Use `rake db:migrate`.

The whole point of `db:schema:load` is that it overwrites your schema. It drops and recreates it, and you cannot alter this behavior. It's baked into the source code with no option to prevent it.

Comment: Hi @meagar and thanks for responding. The problem is I'm missing the migration files so I can't do rake db:migrate , Maybe my question was poorly detailed

Comment: Bad news. I thought I could do schema:load without affecting the existing schema in production + data. Argh, thanks @meagar!

Answer (score 0):

(1) It's bad to destroy migration files for rails.!

(2) Work around: Before doing a db:schema:load, get a db_dump of your database. If you check rake db:migrate:status at this time, all existing migrates should be at status UP. Finally Run rake db:schema:load and then restore your databack.!